# Javascript how to chain multiple promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

In parse I have this crazy query where I'm querying on table1 to get an object.

Then querying table2 on a pointer column that matches table1's result for all users that match that.

Next I need to create an object and then create another object using the result of that first object.

Finally save the final object into the users from table2's query.

I'm having an issue chaining everything and for some reason my success message returns before the user objects are saved.

```
Parse.Cloud.define('startChain', (req, res) => {

let q1 = new Parse.Query("Table1");

q1.equalTo("objectId", req.params.q1ID);
q1.equalTo("user", req.user);
q1.include("user");

q1.get(req.params.q1ID)
.then(post => {
  post.get("user")
  .then(user => {
   // Query on q1
   let q2 = new Parse.Query("Table2");
   q2.equalTo("t1Object", post);
   w2.include("user2");
   q2.include("pointer2Object");
   q2.find();
 })
 .then(users => {
  var morePromises = users.map(aUser => {
    let newObject = new Parse.Object.Extend("Table3");
    newObject.set("user", aUser);
    newObject.set("table1Pointer", post);
    newObject.save()
    .then(result => {
      var object2 = new Parse.Object.Extend("Table4");
      object2.set("column1", aUser);
      object2.set("column2", result);
      var object3 = new Parse.Object.Extend("Table5");
      object2.save()
      .then(o2 => {
        object3.set('column', 'o2');
        object3.save()
        .then(o3 => {
          aUser.set("o3", o3);
          return aUser.save(null, {useMasterKey: true});
        });
      });
    });
  });
  Promise.all(morePromises)
  .then(result => res.success());
})
.catch(err => {
 res.error(err.message);
});
});
});
```

Comment: Surprised that code works at all ... you have too many `})`

Comment: also, you don't return anything inside `users.map(aUser =>` - so there's no promises for `Promise.all` to use

Comment: and one more ... `.then(res.success())` is wrong, .then expects a function as an argument, not the result of calling a function

Comment: one more for luck - `newObject.save().then(result => {` but `result` is never used? why not?

Comment: Result is used now.  And I think I fixed how res.success works.  As far as Promise.all waiting for promises. If I return aUser.save that should fix that issue correct?

Comment: posted an edit please let me know if I'm moving in the right direction

Comment: And, none of the embeded promises (promises created inside `.then()` handlers are getting `return` ed inside the `.then()` handler.  All chaining is lost when you don't return a promise from inside a `.then()` handler.  It creates a new disconnected promise chain.

Comment: not sure if you are moving in the right direction - but https://jsfiddle.net/6a44t4z7/ is getting closer I think

Comment: That JSfiddle link gave me an epiphany and I ended up coming up with a solution based off your example.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the first lines

```
q1.get(req.params.q1ID)
.then(post => {
```

the argument to `then()`'s callback is whatever is returned by `q1.get()`.

Following the same logic, you can chain promises on a single level (i.e. not nested) by returning from a chain block what you need in the next. E.g the above could continue like

```
q1.get(req.params.q1ID)
.then(post => {

   ...

   return q2.find();

 }).then( users => {

     // users is available here

     ...

     return object2.save();

 }).then( o2 => {

 });
```

And so forth...

Comment: How would I do this in a loop where I need to loop over the results of q2.find?

Comment: You could collect all the returns (promises) in an array during interation, then use Promise.all(). But that really should be asked in a new question.

Comment: Would there need to be a return inside of every .then() ?

Comment: A return inside a then will be the argument received by the next then's callback.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should use async await: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

would be much cleaner, code example below:

```
async function yourFunction(x) {
  const result = await q2.find();
  result.map((newObject) => {
      await newObject.save();
  });
}
```

not sure your browser support tho.